# URL parameter in WordPress mod_rewrite URL to fake subpath

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-parameters

**I know there are other questions, but none of them have answers that work for this.**

I have a page on my WordPress site with the slug `profile`, and I have it set up to take a `?username=` URL parameter. However, this is ugly, and I would like to be able to go to `http://website.com/profile/andy` instead of `http://website.com/profile/?username=andy`. Is there something I can put in my `functions.php` to do this? I currently have:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'parameter_queryvars');
function parameter_queryvars($qvars) {
    $qvars[] = 'id';
    $qvars[] = 'username';
    $qvars[] = 'profileredirect';
    $qvars[] = 'reason';
    return $qvars;
}
```

This prevents WordPress from stripping `id`, `username`, `profileredirect`, or `reason` from the URL. Once rewritten, I would still need to be able to use `http://website.com/profile/?profileredirect=true&reason=andy`. I could live without `id`, it's not referenced anywhere and is only there because I haven't removed it.

Thanks!